# How to send a GET request containing a JSON body, using C#?

Tags: c#, json, get

I need to send a GET request to a service that expects JSON in the request body. I understand that GET requests are not meant to be used this way, but I have no control over the service and need to use the existing API, however broken it may be.

So, here's what *doesn't* work:

```
var req = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("localhost:3456");
req.ContentType = "application/json";
req.Method = "GET";
using (var w = new StreamWriter(req.GetRequestStream()))
    w.Write(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new { a = 1 }));
```

It fails with:

```
Unhandled Exception: System.Net.ProtocolViolationException: Cannot send a content-body with this verb-type.
at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.CheckProtocol(Boolean onRequestStream)
at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetRequestStream(TransportContext& context)
at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetRequestStream()
```

Makes sense. How do I bypass this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems the only way to do this is to fall down to using TcpClient directly, so that's what I've done. Here's some example source code that works for me:

```
using (var client = new TcpClient(host, port))
{
    var message =
        $"GET {path} HTTP/1.1\r\n" +
        $"HOST: {host}:{port}\r\n" +
        "content-type: application/json\r\n" +
        $"content-length: {json.Length}\r\n\r\n{json}";

    using (var network = client.GetStream())
    {
        var data = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(message);
        network.Write(data, 0, data.Length);

        using (var memory = new MemoryStream())
        {
            const int size = 1024;
            var buf = new byte[size];
            int read;

            do
            {
                read = network.Read(buf, 0, buf.Length);
                memory.Write(buf, 0, read);
            } while (read == size && network.DataAvailable);

            // Note: this assumes the response body is UTF-8 encoded.
            var resp = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(memory.ToArray(), 0, (int) memory.Length);
            return resp.Substring(resp.IndexOf("\r\n\r\n", StringComparison.Ordinal) + 4);
        }
    }
}
```